# Doubt over applying Cauchy Integral Formula over a triangle

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question:** I have to find the values of $a$ so that $\int_C \left[\frac{1}{(z-2)^4} - \frac{(a-2)^2}{z} + 4\right]d_z$ = $4\pi$, where the closed curve is the triangle having vertices at $i$, $\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt 2}$, $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2}$ and the integral being taken in anti-clockwise direction.

**My approach:** I applied Cauchy's theorem and proved that $\int_C\frac{1}{(z-2)^4}$  and $\int_C 4d_z$ is zero. Since these functions posses no singularity inside the defined closed path which is a triangle. Further I applied cauchy integral formula for $\frac{(a-2)^2}{z}$ and obtained the value of this integral as $-(a-2)^2 2\pi i$. And then further simplifications can give me the values of $a$.

**My doubt:** I am not confident enough to apply the Cauchy integral formula for the triangle. I am not sure that Cauchy integral formula is valid inside the triangle also. If yes, then this imply that value of the $\int_C\frac{1}{z}$ which is $2\pi i$ inside the circle $|z| = 1$ would be same inside any closed curve having, $z = 0$ as an interior point. I need a proper justifications or if possible proofs will work for me.

Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cauchy Integral formula applies to the triangle.  The actual path does not matter, as long as it goes once around the singularity in the counterclockwise direction.  If it is a triangle or a circle does not matter.  It does sound a little bit like magic, but it is essentially the path invariance of the integral $\int_\Gamma f(z) \, dz$, which really follows by Green's theorem.  The path can change as long as it does not cross any singularities.

Really it all boils down to fundamental theorem of calculus (which proves Green's theorem).  Does it also not seem like magic that $\int_a^b f'(t) \, dt$ is determined only by
the value of $f$ at $a$ and $b$?